# How to format a number in localized thousand separator keeping the decimal digits the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some numbers like below

```
double num1 = 123456789.2345;
decimal num2 = 123456789.2M;
```

I want to format them with the localized thousand separator keeping the decimal digits same as it is. I have tried using the below code

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;
Console.WriteLine( num1.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
/* Changed Num1 to Num2 as per question*/
Console.WriteLine( num2.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
```

But it also change the number of decimal digits and produce following output.

```
123,456,789.23
123,456,789.20
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to keep the decimal digit the same?

Comment: Any localized formatter comes in combination of thousand separator and decimal separator of its own. For some cultures "." is thousand separator and "," is decimal separator too. If you want custom one then you need to write your own formatter.

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek because these digits are being controlled by database and it vary on field to field precision and type of accuracy needed for a field.

Comment: @Amit I need to keep the decimal and thousand separators same as locale as well as number of digits. I just need to group those according to the locale thousand separator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this `ToString` Overload any numeric type supports:

```
decimal aNumber = 1234123.12;
string convertedValue = aNumber.ToString("n", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

> convertedValue  = 1,234,123.120

```
string convertedValue = aNumber.ToString("n2", new CultureInfo("it-CH")); //Switzerland
```

> convertedValue  = 1'234'123.12

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings